# SwiftUI: ForEach Unable to infer complex closure return type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

I'm having a strange issue with the ForEach in SwiftUI.

This is the issue: `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`.

if I remove the ForEach and I use just the List, it works, but I need the ForEach because I would like to implement the .onDelete() modifier

```
struct SummaryItemsListView: View {

    var items: [CalendarItem]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item  in
//              if 1 > 0 {
                   Text("hey")
                } else {
                   Text("heu")
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.AgendaColors.foreground)
    }
}



import EventKit

typealias CalendarItem = EKCalendarItem

extension EKCalendarItem: Identifiable {

    public var id: Int {
        return self.hash
    }

    var isTodo: Bool {
        return self is EKReminder
    }

    var isEvent: Bool {
        return self is EKEvent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's getting confused by your conditional statement. Wrap it in a `Group` instead.

```swift
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item  in
                Group {
                    if 1 > 0 {
                        Text("hey")
                    } else {
                        Text("heu")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I assume you will actually be using your conditional in the future and not just checking an always `true` statement. Also as Mojtaba mentioned, you can combine your `ForEach` into the `List` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly declare the return type like this,

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item -> Text  in
```

Comment: What if I have conditional return types? maybe a text or a custom view?

Comment: `List` should be used if you want to return different type of views. `ForEach` will create similar type of list IMO.

Answer (score -1):

If you need some specific modifier like `onDelete` and you NEED to use `ForEach` (as you mentioned in comment) you must ensure compiler about the return type.

For example you can achieve this by using `?:` operator:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item  in
        1 > 0 ? Text("hey") : Text("heu")
    }
    .onDelete { print($0) }
}
```

---

or by explicitly writing the type:

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item -> Text in
    if 1 > 0 {
        return Text("hey")
    } else {
        return Text("heu")
    }
}
```

<sub>Don't forget to write `return` keyword</sub>

Comment: I need the onDelete() modifier available only on ForEach

Comment: Answer Updated.